# Script Javascript se ejecuta 2 veces

Tags: javascript, wordpress

espero se encuentren bien, estaría agradecido de su ayuda. Tengo el siguiente script en Javascript el cual es muy simple. Dicho script se encuentra en un sitio web realizado con Wordpress. Al parecer el elemento al cual señalo ya realiza una función que es añadir la clase **"selected"** al mismo elemento cuando se hace clic sobre el. Por lo tanto mi script así como se ve se ejecuta dos veces, devolviendo dos console.log, Si pongo e.preventDefault() no se añade la clase **selected**, pero si se ejecuta solo una vez. Entonces no se como evitar dicho problema, ya que el botón es generado por un plugin.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(document).on('click','#component_option_radio_buttons_1670887574 ul li > div',function(e){
            // e.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this)[0].dataset.val
            const styles = window.getComputedStyle(this)
            console.log(styles)
            e.preventDefault()
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Compartenos tu HTML, porque lo mas probable es que el esta encontrando 2 de elementos con ese firma.

Answer (score 0):

Se ejecuta múltiples ocasiones, por que estas haciendo click en varios elementos en tu caso => :

**'#component_option_radio_buttons_1670887574,
ul li > div'**

, además del que  e.preventDefault();, esta mal ubicado, debe ser ejecutado antes de inyectar los estilos

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(document).on('click',**'#component_option_radio_buttons_1670887574 ul li > div'**,function(e){
            // e.preventDefault();  => este debe ir descomentado, antes de inyectar los estilos
            let id = $(this)[0].dataset.val
            const styles = window.getComputedStyle(this)
            console.log(styles)
            //e.preventDefault()
        })
    })
</script>
```